# Exit from docker exec -ti in shell script

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I'm writing a script where I execute the following command:

```
docker exec -ti keycloak11_service-keycloak_1 /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh \
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=151 \
-Dkeycloak.migration.action=export  \
-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile \
-Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=demo \
-Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=REALM_FILE \
-Dkeycloak.migration.file=/keycloak/realm-export.json
```

This exports the file realm-export.json from my running keycloak instance. After the execution I want to to do a scp to another server. The problem is, when I execute the ti comment, the standalone keycloak is started and my script stucks while it says : Listening in port ...

As the export operation is finished at that point, I could kill the process or enter any command (which is cmd+c). Is there a way to do this via script?

Comment: Wrap standalone.sh in another script, run it to the background and then run the scp command.

Comment: Could you `docker run` (or `docker-compose run`) a new container, bind-mounting a host directory to receive the output file?

Comment: This is not the best way to do it. But you can try it to run it in the background with an ampersand & After that, not sure how you would know then the export completed?

Answer (score 0):

Put your commands in a Dockerfile and run the container in detached mode `docker run -d`. Also you could use a bind-mount to access a host volume from the container. That way your results are stored on the host and you can access them later.